# How to deal with LVM encryption on remote restart?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, encrypting-file-system

Is there a way to handle the LVM mounting password remotely?  This is usually presented during boot on the main console (where the machine physically resides at).  I am able to ssh in during the prompt, but other services (like http, ftp, etc) will not run until the password is succesfully entered in at boot.  However, ssh does not show the same password prompt that master console shows.  **How do I enter the LVM password remotely on boot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some sort of [KVM over IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28iKVM.29) or a serial console.

Comment: or some inbuilt remote management console like DRAC of iLo, which achieves a similar thing.